# How to pass object via angular 2 in inline javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

Instead of loading HTML component I have created a function with a for each. What it does it goes through 'manifest' and basically is creating components.

I am stuck at that I would like to create an click event that passes the item via the event.

I got the event working as the emi function is working  but it does not pass the 'item', it give me undefined.

How to correct add *(click)="execute(item)"* when you are writing inline JS?

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {button1Component} from 'widgets/buttons1';
import {button2Component} from 'widgets/buttons2';
import {button3Component} from 'widgets/buttons3';

var makeTemplate = function() {

  var template = []
  var manifest = [
        {id: 1, comp: 'button1'},  
{id: 2, comp: 'button2'},  
{id: 3, comp: 'button3'}

]
  manifest.forEach((item) => {
    template.push('<'+item.comp+' (click)="execute(item)">'+'</'+item.comp+'>')
  })

  return template.join("/n")
}


@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: makeTemplate()
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Comment: Not really the Angular way, but if you want to pass value types then in the string building of the template you coud do `(click)="execute(' + item.id + ')">'

Comment: why you think it is not the angular way? When angular compiles , it compiles the HTML into a string and injects into the .ts file and than compress it. Just because I write it differently does mean I am not following what angular rules are. ps thank you the help :)

Comment: You can do a lot of things in many different ways. The framework won't stop you. But instead, you can leverage the structure the framework gives you that make it more clearer to look and maintain. Using ngFor in the view is basically the same as what you are doing here.